# Is Saitou Kichou an assassin in the manga?

Tags: nobunaga-sensei-no-osanazuma

Historically, there is a theory that Saitou Kichou is a spy and assassin sent by her father to assassinate Nobunaga. In the anime *Nobunaga-sensei no Osanazuma*, she indeed seems unhappy (no smiles at all) and always carries a dagger with her, which supports the theory.

I am wondering whether she's actually assumed to be an assassin in the manga.

Comment: I don't know the manga, but having a dagger is just a custom. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiken_(dagger)